# RESTをJSONP形式で返却する（Spring MVC ）

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

JSONP形式で返却するWebAPIを作成したい。（GETメソッド）
環境はSpring4

既にJSON形式で返却するAPIを実装済み。
callbackパラメータを付与したときにJSONP形式で返却したい。

https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/28/spring-framework-4-1-spring-mvc-improvements
上記を参考に、実装したが、実際の結果はJSON形式のままである。

以下のファイルをコントローラと同階層に作成
※作成場所が不明だったため、正しい階層があれば知りたい
サイトを参考に作成

```
@ControllerAdvice
private static class JsonpAdvice extends AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice {
    public JsonpAdvice() {
        super("callback");
    }
}
```

Controller
resultBeanは、Listを含むクラスを定義

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/AAA", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class AAA{
~~
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public resultBean getresult(
@RequestParam(value = "key", required = true) final String key,
final HttpServletRequest request, 
final HttpServletResponse response)
{
~~
return resultBean
}
```

XMLの修正など、情報がなかったため、編集していません。
アノテーションをうまく認識してくれたら、うまくいくのか…
何かお気づきの点・代替案あれば、ご教示ください。

テストにはPOSTMANを使用してます。

Comment: `JsonpAdvice`はスキャン対象パッケージであればどこでも良いはずです(ので、コントローラと同階層、というのは誤りではないです)。 JSONPを得るためのURLは http://localhost:8080/AAA?key=foo&callback=bar のような形になるはずですが、この点は合っているでしょうか。ちなみにリファレンスの記述箇所は[こちら](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.22.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-jsonp)になります。(本題からは逸れますが、ここに記載されている通り、5.1で`AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice`は削除されています。)

Comment: JsonAdviceはClassファイルができたため、私も問題ないと理解しています。URLは、 localhost:8080/AAA?key=foo&callback=callbackとしています。
ですが、結果はJSONの形のまま200ステータスで返却されてしまいます。
AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdviceは参照できました。
他に確認すべき点ありますでしょうか....。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/176593